# SAP Connector Configuration - "Test Connection" in Anypoint Studio fails, but works when deployed

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I'm trying to develop an application with Anypoint Studio and SAP. I imported the SAP connector from Mulesoft Exchange, added the correct SAP libraries (I added them as described by mulesoft --> 'add maven dependency' --> 'install' --> select the local File and change the version to the correct number. All red crosses became green checkmarks.) and entered my SAP server credentials. When I try the "Test Connection" button I get an error message:

[image: error message: 'Test connection failed: Failed to invoke liefecycle phase "initialise" on object: ...']

The confusing part of this is, I can run the application and it deploys without a problem

I already downloaded and unzipped a 'new' anypoint studio, I tried multiple versions of JDK (1.8u201 [this one works without problems for my colleague], 1.8u241 and OpenJDK 8 LTS), I restarted my pc every time I changed my JDK, I tried to add the native JCo Library locally to the build path (checkmark becomes also green, but still the same error message + a lot of 'Building worksapce' errors) and tried to add all libraries to the local build path.

What could I do to get rid of this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution to my problem.

I did everything in a correct way, but I extracted Anypoint Studio in my downloads folder and didn't change anything of the resulting path. So the path was very long and in combination with the libraries the path became too long and they could not be initialized.

So if you get this error try to move the Anypoint Studio folder/Anypoint Studio worksapce/folder where you store the libraries to your root folder (or at least try to keep the path short by changing the folder names).

Comment: This is usually more of a problem in Windows that other OS.

Comment: True, but [according to Mulesoft](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Error-Failed-to-invoke-lifecycle-phase-initialise-on-object-occurred-when-trying-to-test-Connection-in-SAP-Connector) this error is solely caused by incorrect versions of IDOC or JCO or JCO Native libraries being applied to the SAP Connector. So to correct myself: **if the libraries are ok and you still get this error, check out the length of your paths.**